# Foreign key constraint error when inserting to 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a simple registration program using the CodeIgniter framework where the user enters their name, username and password and then these values get stored into my database.

I am having difficulty when I try to insert in to 2 tables, I get a foreign constraint error. Now the 2 tables I have look a like this(excuse my formatting not too sure how to format tables here):

```
Table1
ID INT Auto-Increment Primary key
Username varchar 
Password varchar
```

And my second table

```
Table2
ID INT Foreign key
Name varchar
```

Now my php code I use to add these values:

```
        $data = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $hashpwd);
        $this->db->insert('Table1', $data);
        $profiles = array('name' => $name);
        $this->db->insert('Table2', $profiles);
```

So as you can see I add to table1 first and this query works fine and is inserted into my database, however the second query does not get added to the database and I get the following error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`table2`, CONSTRAINT `table2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `table1` (`ID`))

INSERT INTO `table2` (`name`) VALUES ('John')
```

Can someone how I can add to both tables without having to put the ID in, as I will not know what the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should insert to Table2 also an ID already existing in Table1, not only 'name' field. You can get the id of last insert into Table1 using http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php (php5 required).

Comment: I used CIs built in methods there but yes this is what I done.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `Table2.ID` column nullable.

However, since you've just created the `ID` via the `INSERT` into `Table1`, I think you can just use that newly created ID.

It also seems like `Name` should be on `Table1`, but I'm not positive of what these are actually doing.

Comment: How can I use the newly created ID? I don't want it to be null because I want it to have the same value as that of insert in the first table and then I can use it as an identifier later if I need to. Also no name should be in table 2.

Comment: @user3116846 `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: Can this be put straight into my array or will I need to run a query and then save it in a variable?

Comment: @user3116846 you can do that, or depending on the DB you are using you may be able to get it from codeigniter.  See the API